# Views Overlapping on Samsung S7 Edge Nogut

Tags: android, view, android-7.0-nougat

I have a strange scenario with my application, sometimes views are overlapping 
as shown below.
[image]

What is the problem with views ?

[image]

Comment: I have problem running my app on nougat. It is working fine on android simulator having nougat os but it is not able to run on real device. Can you help me? @Faraz Ahmed

Comment: Hello @KirtiParghi have you seen answer give by Doomsknight, have you tried to remove additional padding in views and check the height of your layout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without seeing the xml.. I assume you have set a height on the containing view. Linear Layout or similar, which is NOT high enough for the contained textview and edit view to be displayed.

Change the `LinearLayout` height to `wrap_content`

Either that, or you may have too much padding/margin on the TextView with a height of match_parent... Try changing these values and see if that helps.